# AsyncTask implementation using NSOperation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I implemented AsyncTask(Android) in iOS using NSOperation subclass.

```
-(id)initWithParam:(NSArray *)params{

if (self = [super init]) {

paramsArray = params;
}
return self;

}

- (void)start {

         @autoreleasepool {

   if (self.isCancelled)
      return;
   NSInteger result;

   result = [self doInBackground:paramsArray];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self postExecute:result];
});
}
}


 - (BOOL) doInBackground: (NSArray *) parameters{

   BOOL status = false;
   int i;
 for (i=0; i<100000; i++) {
     NSLog(@"printing i::%d",i);
 }
 if (i == 100000) {
    status = YES;
 }

return status;
}
- (void) postExecute: (BOOL) deviceState{

   if (deviceState) {
      NSLog(@"Finished");
  }

}

-(BOOL)isConcurrent{

   return YES;
}
```

This is the way I implemented in iOS.Please suggest and any thing I want to add for this functionality.

And also, when can I call isExecuting and isFinished in NSOperation subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question, unfortunately, no, this implementation is not correct. Close, but not quite there.

A couple of things:

1. Your example is not concurrent operation. In the case of `NSOperation`, the term "concurrent operation" (now called an "asynchronous operation") has a special meaning. An asynchronous operation is one that that continues to run asynchronously even after the `start` method finishes. And you designate this by returning `YES` from `isConcurrent` (in older iOS versions) and `isAsynchronous` (in contemporary iOS versions). But the example operation in the question is completely done when `start` ends, so therefore is not an asynchronous operation and therefore `isConcurrent` and `isAsynchronous` should therefore return `NO`.

   Let's assume in this example that you changed `isConcurrent` to return `NO`, as would be appropriate with what you're performing in `start`. That would fix this operation. But don't let this confuse you. If you added this operation to your own operation queue, it would still run asynchronously/concurrently with respect to the main queue, it's just that it's an operation that automatically finishes when `start` finishes, and therefore `isAsynchronous`/`isConcurrent` should return `NO`.
2. You ask "when can I call `isExecuting` and `isFinished`?" Well, you generally don't *call* those methods. You generally *implement* those methods. Specifically, when an asynchronous operation eventually finishes, you must ensure that the app (a) posts KVN for the `isExecuting` and `isFinished` keys; and (b) you override `isExecuting` and `isFinished` to ensure that they correspondingly return the appropriate values.

   You only have to implement this `isExecuting` and `isFinished` code when the operation is truly an asynchronous/concurrent operation. See the *Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution* section of the [Concurrency Programming Guide: Operation Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8). Also see the introductory section of the [`NSOperation` class definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperation).

Whether your operation should be asynchronous or not (or even whether you need to subclass `NSOperation` at all) is unclear. It depends entirely upon what task you want to perform, and whether the task itself runs asynchronously or not.

Comment: Thanks alot @Rob. Actually I put sample there. Actually my task is connecting to custom Wifi device and to read the data from the device. Thats why I choose the NSOperation subclass

Comment: Yeah, that might be a good example of something you'd wrap with `NSOperation` subclass. The question is simply whether the operation is truly concurrent (i.e. `start` would simply initiate the connection and there is some delegate or completion block pattern that would be called later) or not (i.e. `start` would open connection with wifi device and not return until the connection with the device was done). I assume it's the former, but your example in your question is more like the latter.